# rendered animation looks washed out compared to single image render (eevee)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, color-management

When i render a sigle frame, the colors look the way they should, but when I render an animation the colors are pretty signifacntly different. When I render the animation as separate frames the colors are correct again. And the most infuriating part: When I import the frames into After Effects and turn them into a png sequence, the colors are ruined again.

My view transform is set to "standard"

[image: screenshot from after effects sequence]
screenshot from after effects sequence

[image: screenshot from blender rendered animation]
screenshot from blender rendered animation

[image: rendered frame of the animation]
rendered frame of the animation

[image: single render of the scene]
single render of the scene

[image: settings]

[image: settings]
[image: sheet]

Comment: Firstly, from your screenshots, I honestly don't see any quality difference.  Also, are your talking about F12 (menu Render > Image) vs ctl-F12 (menu Render > Animation), versus a Viewport Rendering?

Comment: the difference is in color, not resolution. it is hard to see on the website (because of the white background probably) I am talking about Render > Render animation vs Render > Render image

Comment: Your After Effects work is already a fully formed image, so the encoding is wrong. Your data inside the working space in Blender is linearized to BT.709 closed domain range, therefore the Filmic transformation is incorrect unless you intend to push values outward further. As for the yellowish cast, I suspect this could be After Effects somehow adapting to ICC’s D50 connection space? Hard to know. PNGs are woeful, and codecs are subject to all sorts of problems.

Comment: ok i have tried some more things and this is what i found the problem to be: when i render an image in eeve and save it as png, the colors are as they should but when i render an animation (ffmpeg Video) the colors are different (incorrect). is this a problem that can be resolved? i understand that different formats handle color in different ways but this seems like a pretty big problem. i have added a picture to the original post, there is a comparison of a rendered video (top) and rendered png (bottom) there you can clearly see the difference in color.

Comment: all of the shaders are made with the "Shader to RGB" node, could that be the cause of the problem? if so is there a way to solve this?